# Vertical collection view cells inside horizontal collection view cells do not resize when the device enters from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: ios

I have been trying to implement a vertical collection view inside a horizontal collection view. I have succeeded in my venture up to great extent. But when the device is rotated from portrait to landscape mode, the vertical collection view cells do not resize. Although the cells resize properly when the device enters from landscape to portrait mode. Even the horizontal collection view  cells resize properly as I have invalidated the flow layout inside the viewWillTransitionToSize function. I have implemented the same function (with other functions like numberOfItemsAtIndexPath, cellForItemAt, sizeForItemAt, , etc.) for vertical collection view too (inside a class "HorizontalCollectionViewCell" in a separate CocoaTouch file). But all in vein. All the view and subviews (including the two collection views) have been created using storyboard (not code). I have been searching for the solution for last 1 week , but haven't succeeded yet. Kindly help me find a proper solution for this problem.

Here is the code inside ViewController file:-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var horizontalView: UIView! // Container View for horizontal Collection View.

@IBOutlet weak var horizontalCollectionView: UICollectionView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    horizontalCollectionView.delegate = self
    horizontalCollectionView.dataSource = self
    menuBarCollectionView.delegate = self
    menuBarCollectionView.dataSource = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == menuBarCollectionView {
        let cell = menuBarCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "menuButtonsCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuBarCollectionViewCell

        cell.menuButtonsLabel.text = menuButtonsName[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    let cell = horizontalCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "horizontalCell", for: indexPath) as! HorizontalCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if collectionView == menuBarCollectionView {
        let menuButtonWidthFactor = self.menuBarView.frame.width - 1
        return CGSize(width: menuButtonWidthFactor / 3, height: 35)
    }
    return CGSize(width: horizontalView.frame.width, height: horizontalView.frame.height)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if collectionView == menuBarCollectionView {
        return 0.5
    }

    return 0
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        menuBarCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        horizontalCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
}
```

Here is the code inside subclass HorizontalCollectionViewCell file:-

```
import UIKit

class HorizontalCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

@IBOutlet weak var verticalCollectionView: UICollectionView! {
   didSet {
        self.verticalCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.verticalCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }
}


@IBOutlet weak var verticalView: UIView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = verticalCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "verticalCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: self.verticalView.frame.width, height: 100)
}

func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    verticalCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to make use of `AutoLayout` and `Constraints` ?

Comment: Yes I had. Even I have checked all the constraints twice.